# PyCharm: no autocompletion of Cython package

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm, cython

Scenario:

- own package, build with Cython
- Python 3.5 Interpreter finds my package, executing my Code works
- Python help() also works as expected (methods of classes etc are shown, method signatures are missing)

In PyCharm I set the correct interpreter and my package shows up in the package list (Settings -> Project .. -> Project Interpreter). My package also shows up in the list of Interpreter Paths.

**But: autocompletion and documentation do not work properly** for my package.
Classes seem to be found, as long as the were included in `__all__` of `__init__.py` and the stringdoc for my top module is also shown, but that's it.

I also used "invalidate Caches / Restart" several times.
Any ideas how I could get autocompletion to work?

**Update:** I noticed that PyCharm even creates stubs (that seem correct) but does not use them for auto completion or help.

Comment: same problem, I also find that when validate and restart while indexing is in progress( but before it is completed), autocompletion is work for example : `from libc.stdlib cimport atoi`  BUT after indexing is done autocompletion of these types are not work anymore!!!